# Merging single view app to a storyboard

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, storyboard

This is my first application with multiple views.

I have an app that uses a storybord (main app), and another app with a single viewController and a nib file.

I would like to merge the singleView app as part of the main app. 
Is there a way to do it?
How do I add the nib, and attach it to its viewController?

*Also please state if it's something that is really not recommended to do or not.

Please let me know if any more info needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could simply copy whole view controller from the xib of the "single nib" project to a storyboard project.

- Select "View Controller" in the xib of the single nib project as shown in image below and press cmd+c.

[image: Select View Controller]

- Open storyboard and press cmd+v. Your view controller from xib should be copied as shown in image below.

[image]

- Now you should copy ViewController.m and ViewController.h (or whatever they are called) files from the single nib project.
- Open Finder, find those files and drag them to the storyboard project in Xcode (somewhere in the project navigator). Be sure to select items shown in following image when copy dialog is prompted.
  [image]
- Now you should reconnect outlets and actions to copied view controller .h (cmd + drag from storyboard to .h file - you should already be familiar with this process)

And now you build to see if everything is working.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to just copy your existing single view nibs content into your story board. Just open both projects and copy-paste.

HOWEVER: I usually opt against storyboards. Especially when you're working in a team, they really mess things up (because of their single file/monolithic nature). I'd rather suggest you work on different files for each screen and tie them together with code.

While this may not be a concern for you, it may well be one later on.